# Матрица с помощью наследования от вектора векторов

Tags: c++

Как должен выглядеть конструктор по умолчанию класса, который является наследником STL класса вектор, который содержит вектора (вектора столбцов * количество строк в матрице).

То есть:

```
using std::vector;
...
template<class T>
class Matrix:public Vector<Vector<T>>
public:
Matrix(int m, int n) : Vector(m, Vector<T&>(n, T)){}
```

Не до конца понятно какому полю в таком случае должен присваиваться новый векторный вектор, так как это наследования. 
Ведь при наследование не создается конструктор по умолчанию, как в таком случае должен выглядеть этого класса ? 
Идея по-моему в цикле который при каждом шаге вызовет конструктор по умолчанию **Vector**. Может кто подсказать ?

Comment: используйте агрегирование (то есть, вектор векторов должен быть полем), а не наследуйтесь. std::vector имеет невиртуальный деструктор и не предназначен для наследования.

Comment: Но ведь и деструктор не наследуется, можно ведь определить новый как вирутальный, нет ?

Comment: а то есть в самом векторном векторе он не вирутальный, а точно, я верно вас понял ? 
Плохо знаком с русской терминолгией, агрегирование это вы имеете ввиду в классе Матрица будет поле векторный вектор, так ?

Comment: Кстати, но если нет никаких дополнительных полей, и мне допустим нужна только способност возвращать элементы из матрицы, какая мне разница, что диструктор не виртуальный ? То есть мы говорим об очень конкретном задание, без многофункциональности и т.д 
Возможно в этом случае это даже эффективный способ, нет ?

Comment: В целом, наследоваться можно. Но не рекомендуется. Проблема с деструктором высосана из пальца — много видели полиморфного кода с контейнерами? Но вот по рукам такое наследование может дать. Я как-то патч делал для Qt, когда MSVC2010 вышла и поломала WebKit(кажется, я уже точно не помню) Qt из-за того, что у них был тип, который наследовался от стандартного контейнера. Я не помню всех подробностей, но одной из причин было то, что стандартный контейнер может наследоваться от массы других сущностей — это не запрещено и как это отразиться в будущем, не известно.

Comment: @Ilya.K. На счет виртуального деструктора не столь критично, но чтобы вы знали в чем может быть проблема советую посмотреть [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117996/) раздел "Зачем нужен виртуальный деструктор?" Но вообще, и правда стоит предпочесть композицию наследованию.

Answer (score 1):

Агрегация - это связь объектов, когда один как бы является частью другого и существует только пока существует породивший его объект. Я бы сделал матрицу так:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    vector<vector<T>*> _values;
public:
    Matrix(int m, int n) : _values(m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            _values[i] = new vector<T>(n);
    }

    T& operator[] (int i) {
        return _values[i];
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _values.size(); i++) {
            delete _values[i];
        }
    }
};
```

И обращение по двум индексам работает как надо:

```
    Matrix<int> temp(3, 4);
    temp[1][2] = 3;
    int k = temp[1][2];
    cout << k << "\n";
```

Comment: Да, я примерно также реализовал без наследования только не вижу необходимости в использование адрессов, и динамического выделения памяти